# Как назначить макрос из VBA excel на фигуру

Tags: excel, vba

создал я фигуру:

```
Sub gen_button()
    l = ActiveSheet.Range("H10:H11").Left
    t = ActiveSheet.Range("H10:H11").Top
    w = ActiveSheet.Range("H10:H11").Width
    h = ActiveSheet.Range("H10:H11").Height

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, l, t, w, h).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Selection.Text = "Генерировать"
    Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Selection.HorizontalAlignment = 1
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)

End Sub
```

Но так же я хочу на неё назначить вызов макроса, как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте свойство [`OnAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834436%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

```
Sub gen_button()
    l = ActiveSheet.Range("H10:H11").Left
    t = ActiveSheet.Range("H10:H11").Top
    w = ActiveSheet.Range("H10:H11").Width
    h = ActiveSheet.Range("H10:H11").Height

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, l, t, w, h)
    shp.OnAction = "Shape_Click"
    shp.Select

    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Selection.Text = "Генерировать"
    Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Selection.HorizontalAlignment = 1
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)


End Sub

Sub Shape_Click()
    MsgBox "test"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Попутно.

Используйте в макросах оператор *With/End With*. В такой записи код приятнее глазу )

Но не это главное. Родитель определяется один раз, код работает быстрее

```
Sub gen_button()
    With Range("H10:H11")
        l = .Left: t = .Top: w = .Width: h = .Height
    End With

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, l, t, w, h)

    With shp
        .OnAction = "Shape_Click"
        .Select

        With Selection
            .ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
            .Text = "Генерировать"
            .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .HorizontalAlignment = 1
            .ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```